# Moving items from listbox1 to listbox2 and back vbnet winform

Tags: vb.net, listbox

I need to move selected items from listbox1 to listbox2 and back.
To do that first I retrieve data from a server and fill a datatable with two columns (name and id).
Next I bind the datatable to listbox1 in order to have name as a displayname and id as a value.
Now I want to move only the selected items from listbox1 to listbox2 (let's call it basket).
While doing that I want that all the selected items moved into listbox2 disappear from the listbox1.
In case of mistake I want to be able to move back selected items from the listbox2 to the listbox1.
While doing that I want that selected items from listbox2 disappear and become available again in listbox1.
When done all the items in listbox2 will be processed using their name and id.
I hope that everything is clear and thank you in advance for any suggest or help.

Answer (score 0):

For me, it will be looks like this

[image: Screenshot]

```
    Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        ListBox2.Items.Add(ListBox1.SelectedItem)
        ListBox1.Items.Remove(ListBox1.SelectedItem)
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        ListBox1.Items.Add(ListBox2.SelectedItem)
        ListBox2.Items.Remove(ListBox2.SelectedItem)
    End Sub
End Class
```

In this code i have used 2 listboxes, ListBox1 and ListBox2 and to shuffle selected items in each, i coded 1st button move items from LB1 to LB2 and used 2nd button to move selected item from LB2 to LB1. If you want to store same records in your database, use update method to update.